# How to calculate Skewness and Kurtosis in a similar manner as a weighted average in Excel?

Tags: excel, statistics, skew, kurtosis

I would like to compute some descriptive statistics about the following table of information. The main thing that I like to describe is the Price component.

```
Price   Qty
  493     5
 4500     8
 2107    14
  269     1
```

The weighted average is straight forward with `=sumproduct(Price,Qty)/sum(Qty)`. However it gets more challenging when I want to calculate the `=skew()` and `=kurt()`. In an ideal situation I would have data that isn't aggregated, but unfortunately I only have aggregated data.

Does anybody have a smart idea about how to get the skewness and kurtosis in Excel using the above data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, but I don't think you're going to like the answer, since Excel functions don't work with aggregate data.

First way would be to unroll the data.

```
Price
493
493
493
493
493
4500
4500 (x 7 more times, one per row)
2107
2107 (x 13 more times, one per row)
269
```

Skew, kurtosis, and standard deviation will all work great with data unrolled.

Here's another way.

Extending your example:

```
Price Qty AggPrice
 493   5    2465
4500   8   36000
2107  14   29498
 269   1     269

AggPrSum   =sum(c2:c5)
mean       =sum(c2:c5)/sum(b2:b5)
```

You may then calculate the skew by applying the [equation](http://ncalculators.com/statistics/skewness-calculator.htm). When you calculate the mean, the rest should become clear. (You can start by adding a new column D which is price minus the mean, the difference cubed.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first options is indeed what I have been thinking about. The second option is not really practical when you have to apply it a number of times. However, this reminds me very much about the examples from my statistics textbooks. Guess a piece of VBA will be my friend for the solution. Thanks again.